# Django create a custom form permission

Tags: python, django, permissions

I'm developing a management software. And I need create a module for manage the permissions and  groups using the auth of django. I dont want use the admin django because this just allow log in for super users.

I want override the admin route and create a form with the same features from the admin site. If is possible, I want use the widget for the assignment of permission and group.

I need all this built into an app because I need this to work for this and other projects.

I have already written a custom form to add, edit and view users extending the class `UserCreationForm`, I need something similar to that.

I hope you can help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: don't do this!
Creating your own Django admin site is a load of work, and likely to be insecure etc. Your'e opening a giant can of worms here.
If you need members of your app to edit permissions, they *do not have to be superusers*! Users with `is_staff = True` can all access the admin site. Once you've set this for the users you want, go ahead and configure the exact permissions for this type of user.
Start with the official docs [on user permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization).

Comment: Oh! its true, i can set the staff on true. But i need custom the template and the url for the admin django. Because i dont need all fetures from django admin. I only need the permission and group manage module.

Edit 1:
I also need this look like mi whole app, with my css style... But using the widget for the manage permission and group.